# Subclassing NSLayoutConstraint, bizarre behavior of constants

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

On whatever project you're currently working on, simply

1. On any screen drop in a UIView
2. Just add a width constraint (666 or whatever is fine),
3. Change the custom class of the constraint, to `Constrainty`
4. Run the app,

> [image]

**How can this possibly be?**

Does it actually call for the value of the constant, "before the class is initialized," or some such?

How can it happen, and how to solve?

At first, I had the two variables as `@IBInspectable` and I was surprised that didn't work at all.  But then I changed them to ordinary let constants - and that doesn't work!

```
class Constrainty: NSLayoutConstraint {

    let percentageWidth: CGFloat = 77 // nothing up my sleeve
    let limitWidth: CGFloat = 350

    override var constant: CGFloat {

        get { return teste() }
        set { super.constant = newValue }
    }

    func teste()->CGFloat {

        print("\n\n HERE WE GO \(percentageWidth) \(limitWidth) \n\n")

        if let sw = (firstItem as? UIView)?.superview?.bounds.width {

            let w = sw * ( percentageWidth / 100.0 )
            let r = w > limitWidth ? limitWidth : w
            print("result is \(r) \n\n")
            return r
        }

        return 50
    }

}
```

Comment: Someone has to know this!

Comment: My guess (to check the Doc, but I'm not a Swift developer), your object "has no init" so its values are not set for its properties. Strangely, it doesn't call `init()`, nor has a `initWithCoder:`/`awakeFromNib` that should be the one to be called when a UI object is init through a xib/storyboard. So I'd say that the value are then no set. Like a weird object with no init called (I tried to override init, and wasn't called).

Comment: `initWithCoder:` is being called when an `NSLayoutConstraint`(or it's subclass) is being initialized from the Interface Builder file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My wild guess it's all because of a class named `UIClassSwapper`. It's a private class that handles all the UI objects initialization from the Interface Builder files. I would suggest to replace your `let` constants with computed properties.

```
//...
var percentageWidht: CGFloat { // nothing up my sleeve
    return 77.0
}

var limitWidth: CGFloat {
    return 110.0
}
//...
```

**UPD**

Swift *default property values*(properties with values in their declaration) are being set before the initializer call. E.G. if you have a class `MyClass` with a property `let someVar: CGFloat = 12.0` and it's bridged to Objective-C, when you allocate memory for your object and do not call an initializer `MyClass *obj = [MyClass alloc]` your variable will have a default value of 0.0 and will stay so unless you’ll call an initializer like `[obj init]`. So my second wild guess is that because `NSLayoutConstraint` class is written in Objective-C and it's `initWithCoder:` initializer isn't declared in it's header(it's private), the ObjC-Swift bridging mechanism doesn't recognize it's call as an initializer call(it thinks it is just a simple instance method), so your Swift properties with default values aren't being initialized at all.

Comment: Good Lord.  I have never heard of `UIClassSwapper` in my whole wide life!

Comment: Thanks!  indeed this is the quick fix, and you explained this surprising behaviour!

Answer (score 10):

I don't think it's a good idea to subclass `NSLayoutConstraint`. I don't think it was designed to be subclassed outside of Apple.

Anyway, the problem is that `NSLayoutConstraint` conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol, but doesn't declare that it conforms to `NSCoding` in the header files. Because of this, Swift doesn't know that `NSLayoutConstraint` can be initialized by `-[NSLayoutConstraint initWithCoder:]`, so it doesn't generate an override of `initWithCoder:` that initializes the instance variables you add in your subclass.

Here's how to fix it.

First, if your project doesn't have a bridging header, add one. The easiest way to add one is to create a new Objective-C class in your project, accept Xcode's offer to create the bridging header, then delete the `.h` and `.m` files it created for the class (but keep the bridging header).

Then, in the bridging header, declare that `NSLayoutConstraint` conforms to `NSCoding`:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

@import UIKit;

@interface NSLayoutConstraint (MyProject) <NSCoding>
@end
```

Finally, in your `Constrainty` class, override `init(coder:)` like this:

```
required init(coder decoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: decoder)!
}
```

Et voila:

```
 HERE WE GO 77.0 350.0 


result is 246.4
```

Comment: Interesting solution, I'm pretty sure this will work, but don't you think there is some kind of private API call (`super.init(coder: decoder)!`) and there is a chance to be rejected by Apple on app submission?

Comment: @VahanBabayan - init#coder is commonly used all the time; it's not private or anything. (Sorry if I misunderstood you.)

Comment: @Fattie Yes, `NSCoding` is a public protocol. But you are "publishing" `NSLayoutConstraint`'s private implementation of that protocol in your category and then using it in your own code. I'm pretty sure it is a violation of [Apple Developer Program's section 3.3.1](https://developer.apple.com/programs/information/Apple_Developer_Program_Information_8_12_15.pdf).

Comment: @VahanBabayan Whether this violates §3.3.1 is questionable. I could argue for either position. I agree that my solution is risky, which is why I wrote “I don't think it's a good idea to subclass `NSLayoutConstraint`.”

Comment: It would also be reasonable to [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com/) asking for the conformance to `NSCoding` to be made public. That might at least get a response indicating that you aren't supposed to subclass `NSLayoutConstraint`.

Comment: Fascinating stuff!  Not that it means anything, but, `init#coder` just pops up normally in the autocomplete in XCode when you're subclassing NSLayoutConstraint.

Comment: My experience is that autocomplete only offers `init(coder:)` in `Constrainty` if you've done the bridging header hack I described.